How to make instant app and app clip from React Native app?
I have a react native app built on top of ignite template. I use react navigation like this:
import React from "react"
import { ImageSourcePropType, useColorScheme } from "react-native"

import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  NavigationContainer,
  NavigatorScreenParams,
} from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack"
import * as Screens from "app/screens"
import { isAuthenticatedSelector, useStore } from "app/store"

import Config from "../config"

import { navigationRef, useBackButtonHandler } from "./navigationUtilities"
import { Navigator, TabParamList } from "./Navigator"


export type AppStackParamList = {
  Introduction: undefined
  EmailSignIn: undefined
  …
  //  Your screens go here
}


const exitRoutes = Config.exitRoutes

export type AppStackScreenProps<T extends keyof AppStackParamList> = NativeStackScreenProps<
  AppStackParamList,
  T
>

// Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppStackParamList>()

const AppStack = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useStore(isAuthenticatedSelector)

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      initialRouteName={isAuthenticated ? "Screen1" : "Introduction"}
    >
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Navigator" component={Navigator} />
          <Stack.Screen name=“Screen1” component={Screens.Screen1} />
    …
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Introduction" component={Screens.IntroductionScreen} />
    …
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export interface NavigationProps
  extends Partial<React.ComponentProps<typeof NavigationContainer>> {}

export const AppNavigator = (props: NavigationProps) => {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()

  useBackButtonHandler((routeName) => exitRoutes.includes(routeName))

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      theme={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
      {...props}
    >
      <AppStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

What i want is to have 3-4 of my screens as an instant app for android, app clip for ios. They should be opened when a QR code is scanned. This is my current app.tsx mostly configured by the ignite template. I don't know how to handle the linking part. For my main app, i don't need linking but for the instant app the QR that users scan should open the instant app/app clip.

import "react-native-get-random-values"
// polyfill for nanoid
import "./i18n"
import "./utils/ignoreWarnings"

import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { ViewStyle } from "react-native"

import { QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { useFonts } from "expo-font"
import * as Linking from "expo-linking"
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler"
import { initialWindowMetrics, SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context"
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message"

import Config from "./config"
import { AppNavigator } from "./navigators/AppNavigator"
import { useNavigationPersistence } from "./navigators/navigationUtilities"
import { ErrorBoundary } from "./screens/ErrorScreen/ErrorBoundary"
import { queryClient, useStore } from "./store"
import { customFontsToLoad } from "./theme"
import * as storage from "./utils/storage"


export const NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY = "NAVIGATION_STATE"

// Web linking configuration
const prefix = Linking.createURL("/")
const config = {
  screens: {
    // I don’t know how to set this up
}

interface AppProps {
  hideSplashScreen: () => Promise<boolean>
}


function App(props: AppProps) {
  const { hideSplashScreen } = props
  const {
    initialNavigationState,
    onNavigationStateChange,
    isRestored: isNavigationStateRestored,
  } = useNavigationPersistence(storage, NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY)

  const [areFontsLoaded, fontLoadError] = useFonts(customFontsToLoad)

  const hasHydrated = useStore((state) => state._hasHydrated)

  useEffect(() => {
    const hideScreen = async () => {
      if (hasHydrated && isNavigationStateRestored && areFontsLoaded && !fontLoadError) {
        try {
          await hideSplashScreen()
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error hiding splash screen:", error)
        }
      }
    }

    hideScreen()
  }, [hasHydrated, isNavigationStateRestored, areFontsLoaded, fontLoadError, hideSplashScreen])

  if (!hasHydrated || !isNavigationStateRestored || !areFontsLoaded) {
    return null
  }

  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config,
  }

  // otherwise, we're ready to render the app

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
        <ErrorBoundary catchErrors={Config.catchErrors}>
          <GestureHandlerRootView style={$container}>
            <AppNavigator
              linking={linking}
              initialState={initialNavigationState}
              onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            />
            <Toast />
          </GestureHandlerRootView>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

export default App

const $container: ViewStyle = {
  flex: 1,
}

So how do i make this instant app/app clip functionality? What should be my folder structure? What tools can i use? I won't have any payment structure in the app clips. I will have some backend fetches/posts inside the screens but these backend operations will be based on whether we're in app clip or full app. I have to be able to detect that.
I couldn't find much resources online. I found this app-clip-instant-app-react-native repo but I couldn't understand how will i structure my app.
